# Best way to allow web page visitors to enlarge view of embedded YouTube video?

Tags: embedded-video

(Altho' I know some CSS, I'm completely new to using video.)

To have my own YouTube video fit well my web page design, I want to embed it in a small format (560 x 315).  However, I would like visitors to be able to choose YouTube's 'cinema' or 'full screen' views, if they wish.  Are these options available when embedding YouTube videos?

Similarly: 
How can I make such an embedded video open onto a dedicated web page in my own site, rather than to an actual YouTube page?

Thanks!